# Conditionally execute a graphql mutation after a query is fetched

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-component, apollo-client, vue-composition-api

**Scenario**

When a user is authenticated (`isAuthenticated` booelan ref):

1. Check if a user has preferences by a graphql call to the backend (`useViewerQuery`)
2. If there are no preferences for the user set the default (`useSetPreferenceDefaultMutation`)

**Problem**

Both the query and the mutation work correctly in the graphql Playground and in the Vue app. They have been generated with the [graphql codegenerator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-vue-apollo) which uses [useQuery](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-mutation.html) and [useMutation](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-mutation.html) in the background.

The issue we're having is that we can't define the correct order. Sometimes `useSetPreferenceDefaultMutation` is executed before `useViewerQuery`. This resets the user's settings to the defaults and it not the desired behavior.

Also, on a page refresh all is working correctly. However, when closing an reopening the page it always calls `useSetPreferenceDefaultMutation`.

**Code**

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const {
      result: queryResult,
      loading: queryLoading,
      error: queryError,
    } = useViewerQuery(() => ({
      enabled: isAuthenticated.value,
    }))

    const {
      mutate: setDefaultPreferences,
      loading: mutationLoading,
      error: mutationError,
      called: mutationCalled,
    } = useSetPreferenceDefaultMutation({
      variables: {
        language: 'en-us',
        darkMode: false,
      },
    })

    onMounted(() => {
      watchEffect(() => {
        if (
          isAuthenticated.value &&
          !queryLoading.value &&
          !queryResult.value?.viewer?.preference &&
          !mutationCalled.value
        ) {
          void setDefaultPreferences()
        }
      })
    })

    return {
      isAuthenticated,
      loading: queryLoading || mutationLoading,
      error: queryError || mutationError,
    }
  },
})
```

**Failed efforts**

- We opened an issue [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/1066) and [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/1065) to have extra options on `useQuery` or `useMutation` which could help in our scenario but no luck.
- Use `fetch` option with `sync` or `post` on `watchEffect`
- Use `watch` instead of `watchEffect`

Comment: use 'skip' option

Comment: `skip` is the same as `enabled` in Vue I believe. The query is correctly executed after `isAuthenticated` is set to `true` so that's not the issue. The problem is that the mutation is sometimes executed first.

Comment: On a page refresh it works as intended but on closing the page an re-opening it always calls the mutation. This makes me think the conditions are correct in the `if` clause. There is no `enabled` option on a mutation, it is only called in the `watchEffect` clause with `setDefaultPreferences()`

Comment: just use `onCompleted` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comment from @xadm it's fixed now by using the [onResult event hook](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-query.html#return) on the query, so it will execute the mutation afterwards.

> onResult(handler): Event hook called when a new result is available.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup(_, { root }) {
    const {
      loading: queryLoading,
      error: queryError,
      onResult: onQueryResult,
    } = useViewerQuery(() => ({
      enabled: isAuthenticated.value,
    }))

    const {
      mutate: setDefaultPreferences,
      loading: mutationLoading,
      error: mutationError,
    } = useSetPreferenceDefaultMutation({
      variables: {
        language: 'en-us',
        darkMode: false,
      },
    })

    onQueryResult((result) => {
      if (!result.data.viewer.preference) {
        void setDefaultPreferences()
      }
    })

    return {
      isAuthenticated,
      loading: queryLoading || mutationLoading,
      error: queryError || mutationError,
    }
  },
})
```